# C++ a function call is not called again after the loop iterates

Tags: c++, function, loops, function-call

Hey so I am relatively a beginner at programming. I am trying to create a very simple minesweeper game over a 2D array, the issue I am running into is after the player steps on a mine (game over) they are given the option to play again. After this the set difficulty function is supposed to be called a second time (since it is within the loop) and a new minefield is to be generate. Unfortunately none of that is happening and the program skips that process.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int choose_difficulty(int x);
int generator();

int main()
{
    //create initial variables
    string Ans;
    int Rounds;
    int NewPosition_x = 0;
    int NewPosition_y = 0;

    //ask user if he wants to run the program and expect input
    cout << "Would you like to play a game? Y/N" << endl;
    cin >> Ans;

    //based on user input the program will run or not
    if (Ans == "Y" || "y") {

        while (Ans == "Y" || "y")
        {
    //Create position variables to be checked
            int Position_x;
            int Position_y;
            //ask user how many rounds in the game they want
            cout << "How many chances do you want to give yourself?" << endl;
            cin >> Rounds;

//Generate minefield could not be done as separate function since you cannot output an array
                int a = choose_difficulty(a);
                int mines;
                int n,m;

                srand (time (0));

                if(a == 0) {
                    mines = 3;
                    n = 4;
                    m = n;
                }
                else if (a == 1){
                    mines = 5;
                    n = 4;
                    m = n;
                }
                else if (a == 2){
                    mines = 7;
                    n = 4;
                    m = n;
                }
                int minefield[n][m] = { };
                int g, h;

                for (int num = 0; num < mines; num++) {
                    g = rand()%n;
                    h = rand()%n;

                    minefield[g][h] = 1;
                }

            for (int x = 0; x < Rounds; x++)
            {
                //Begin Game
                cout << "Where are you at to avoid the mines? (Enter a 2 numbers 0 through 3)" << endl;
                cin >> NewPosition_x >> NewPosition_y;

                //check if the player has entered a new position
                while (NewPosition_x == Position_x && NewPosition_y == Position_y) {
                    cout << "You have to move somewhere, put a valid location" << endl;
                    cin >> NewPosition_x >> NewPosition_y;
                }
                //check to see if that position is valid
                while ((NewPosition_x < 0 || NewPosition_x > 3) || (NewPosition_y < 0 || NewPosition_y > 3)) {
                    cout << "I'm sorry, but that place doesn't exist. Try somewhere else" << endl;
                    cin >> NewPosition_x >> NewPosition_y;
                }
                //Assign Player Position and check position vs mines
                Position_x = NewPosition_x;
                Position_y = NewPosition_y;
                if (minefield[Position_y][Position_x] == 1) {
                    cout << "You stepped on a mine, Game Over" << endl;

                    cout << "You minefield was this:" << endl;
                    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
                    for (int j=0; j < n; j++){
                            cout << minefield[i][j] << "\t";
                            }
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                    cout << "Would you like to play again? Y/N" << endl;
                    cin >> Ans;
                    if (Ans == "n" || Ans == "N"){
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                else if ((minefield[Position_x + 1][Position_y] == 1) || (minefield[Position_x - 1][Position_y] == 1) || (minefield[Position_x][Position_y + 1] == 1) || (minefield[Position_x][Position_y - 1] == 1)) {
                    cout << "You're hot right now, you better watch your step. Continue to the next round" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You're safe. Continue to the next round" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}

int choose_difficulty(int a)
{
    do{
        string difficulty;

        //Difficulty Selection
        cout << "Choose the game difficulty: Easy, Medium, Hard" << endl;
        cin >> difficulty;

        if (difficulty == "easy" || difficulty == "Easy"){
            a = 0;
        }
        else if (difficulty == "medium" || difficulty == "Medium"){
            a = 1;
        }
        else if (difficulty == "hard" || difficulty == "Hard"){
            a = 2;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid input";
            a = 3;
        }
    }while (a == 3);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: `if (Ans == "Y" || "y") {` and `(Ans == "Y" || "y")` are wrong!

Comment: `Ans == "Y" || "y"` -- This does not do what you think it does.  C++ logical statements aren't the same as English-speak.

Comment: See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` so you will only need to compare once, such as `if (std::toupper(Ans[0]) == 'Y')`.

Comment: you should learn to use functions to split your code into small pieces. If a block of code does not fit onto my screen my brain gets a stackoverflow.

Comment: @tobi303: But this is StackOverflow, so that's fine. ;-) I admit I get a bit uneasy if I see a long block of code too.

Comment: `int minefield[n][m] = { };` -- This is not legal C++ syntax, since `n` and `m` are variables.  Arrays in C++ can only have constants or constant expressions to denote the number of entries.

Comment: `if (Ans == "n" || Ans == "N"){`  -- Why didn't you make the same mistake here?  This line of code is ok, but for some reason, you abandoned the correct way and did it wrong for the two lines that have been pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the if statement thing. but that did not fix the error. after going through the loop once, restarting the game will go back to the beginning of the for loop. I cannot figure out why though.....
For the array, that was a short hand that I used to test what size of array would work best for the game. Thank you for letting me know that's poor syntax, they don't teach those things these days.

Comment: @tobi303 I tried splitting my program into separate functions. The problem comes where I can't pass an array between functions (something I commented on within the program).

Comment: if you use `std::vector` you will never again have a problem passing arrays around

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful on this kind of error:

```
//based on user input the program will run or not
    if (Ans == "Y" || "y") {

        while (Ans == "Y" || "y")
        {
```

This, above, will always be true being "*y*" different from 0 (false).

Instead you need to check that Ans is either equal to "*Y*" or "*y*" in this way:

```
//based on user input the program will run or not
    if (Ans == "Y" || Ans == "y") {

        while (Ans == "Y" || Ans == "y")
        {
```

Or use, as suggested in the comments, `std::toupper()`

---

### UPDATE

It seems you have a problem on your buffer you should use [cin.ignore()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) in order to clean it;

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but that did not fix the error. after going through the loop once, restarting the game will go back to the beginning of the for loop. I cannot figure out why though.....

Comment: @CoreySmith  how can you run your code with this line?                 __int minefield[n][m] = { };__

Comment: my compiler in able to understand it and create an array of n/m dimension (I have it as 4 x 4) that is filled with 0's until I fill it with 1's in random places in the subsequent loop.

Comment: @CoreySmith I think it's not C++, however, as you can see [here](http://cpp.sh/4w64i) it seems restarting the game.. If not explain better your problem and provide more details on what do you expect and what is not working

Comment: It does restart if you go through the rounds, I does not restart properly If you lose and you are asked to restart. I just tried your link. I expect to see the same dialog to appear if you go through all the rounds and if I answered "y" to play again after stepping on a mine.

Comment: @CoreySmith when you say __I expect to see the same dialog__ to which dialog do you refer to?

Comment: What I am referring to is what the user would see. Here is an example:
{You stepped on a mine, Game Over
You minefield was this:
1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 1 
1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 
Would you like to play again? Y/N
y
Where are you at to avoid the mines? (Enter a 2 numbers 0 through 3)}
Instead displaying "Where are you at to avoid the mines" it should display "How many chances do you want to give yourself?" I can't format how I want it to look.

Comment: @CoreySmith I got your problem. That's a problem into the buffer try to use cin.ignore(10,'\n'); before the cin >> Rounds; like [here](http://cpp.sh/2qnxa)